# Pygame window is not showing up

Tags: python, pygame

I have python 3.10.5 and Pygame 2.1.2. I dont know whats happening, but my window is not showing up. i have tried changing the code a bit, but nothing seems to be working.

```py
import pygame

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 900, 500
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))

def main():
    run = True
    while run:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False

    pygame.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Can you try adding `pygame.display.flip()` to the main loop?

Comment: I tried that, but the window still didnt show up. I just tried that same code on a different editor, and it actually worked. I think the problem is the editor i was using, sublime text. I checked for updates, but it seems to have the latest version.

Comment: Sublime text does not execute python code directly, it needs a python kernel. How are you running your python programs?

Comment: I've been running my programs just fine. I'm a beginner so I'm not running anything too complex.

Comment: It should be like this if __name__ == "__main__":  and not this if name == 'main': main()

Comment: There is no problem with this code. If the window does not show, the problem is with your system, not with the code.

Answer (score 1):

I tried out your initial code and found some bits missing as noted in the comments.  I did not see any reference to what color would be used for filling your screen along with the missing "display.flip().  Keeping the spirit of your initial code as much intact as possible, following is a code snippet that does present a white game window.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 900, 500

WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))

def main(): 
    run = True 
    
    while run:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
                
        WIN.fill((255, 255, 255))  # Added this
        
        pygame.display.flip()      # And this

    pygame.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

You might also want to check out the following link for other tips [Pygame Primer](https://realpython.com/pygame-a-primer/).